# Ionic 3 android sms app not opening with sms url

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Hey guys I am having issues being able to open android sms app.  It works fine for iOS but not sure why it is not working with android.  This is what the html looks like:
`<h5 class="padding5"><a [href]="sanitize('sms:' + custPhone)"><ion-icon class="contactIcons" name="text"></ion-icon></a></h5>`

Here is what the sanitize function looks like:
`sanitize(url: string) {
  return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
}`